# Which should I use mail outbound-channel-adapter or org.springframework.mail.MailSender

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-integration

I have too many emails. I want to send messages to them. each one have different message text and attachment. I want to send emails parallel, because I have too many emails I think multithreading will solve the problem well.

Some people told  that that I should use **org.springframework.mail.MailSender** for this.  And then I can use ExecutorService to send emails with many threads.

Some people told me that I should use Spring integration for this. I found in doc the following ***"Spring Integration provides a number of adapters out of the box to support various transports, such as JMS, File, HTTP, Web Services, and Mai*"**

I do not understand **should I use spring integration or not? Or when should I use it? what benefit does it have?  what disadvantage does  org.springframework.mail.MailSender have? Is spring integration better? why?**

I know how to send emails, but I do not know which library should I use? Spring Integration or Just MailSender class?